# How to push array containts objects to object with key using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an object like this:

```
var obj = {
    name: $('#name').val(),
    age:  $('age').val()
};
```

And I have an array object like this

```
var arrObj = [
    {level: 10, status: 1},
    {level: 8, status: 0}
];
```

I want to push my array to an object with a defined key, and expected result:

```
{
    name: 'Name A',
    age:  30,
    level: [
        {level: 10, status: 1},
        {level: 8, status: 0}
    ]
}
```

But I don't know how to push my array to object with a key. I tried:

```
var obj = {
    name: $('#name').val(),
    age:  $('age').val(),
    level: []
};

obj['level'].push(arrObj);
```

But I will make my level element have 1 more array level like this:

```
{
    name: 'Name A',
    age:  30,
    level:[ 
        [
            {level: 10, status: 1},
            {level: 8, status: 0}
        ]
    ]
}
```

How I can get the results I expected.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with the spread operator

```
obj['level'].push(...arrObj);
```

Answer (score 3):

An array can be directly assigned to an object using `=` (assignment operator)

You can try out assigning an array of objects to the level key by following.

```js
var obj = {
    name: 'Name A',
    age:  30,
    level: []
};
var arrObj = [
    {level: 10, status: 1},
    {level: 8, status: 0}
];

obj.level = arrObj //arrObj's value will be overwritten to level key and if such key doesn't exist then it'll be created!

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this

`obj.level = arrObj;`

The `level` property within `obj` will be created on the fly if such property doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) in place of `push`:

```js
var obj = {
    name: 'Name A',
    age:  30,
    level: []
};
var arrObj = [
    {level: 10, status: 1},
    {level: 8, status: 0}
];

obj.level = obj.level.concat(arrObj);

console.log(obj)
```